# I want to create a perl code to extract what is in the parentheses and port it to a variable

Tags: perl

I want to create a perl code to extract what is in the parentheses and port it to a variable. 
"(05-NW)HPLaserjet" should become "05-NW"
Something like this:

- Catch "("
- take out any spaces that exsist in between ()
- everything in between () = variable 1

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $s = '(05-NW)HPLaserjet';
my ($v) = $s =~ /\((.*)\)/; # Grab everything between parens (including other parens)
$v =~ s/\s//g; # Remove all whitespace
print "$v\n";

__END__

05-NW
```

See also: [Perl Idioms Explained - @ary = $str =~ m/(stuff)/g](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=291543)

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for regular expressions. Looks confusing because parens are used as meta characters in regular expression and are also part of the pattern in your example, escaped by backslashes.

```
C:\temp $ echo (05-NW)HPLaserjet | perl -nlwe "print for m/\(([^)]+)\)/g"
```

Match opening paren, start capture group, match one or more characters that aren't the closing paren, close capture group, match closing paren.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions (see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)) to match and capture the value. By assigning to a list, you can put your captures into named variables. The global variables `$1`, `$2` etc. are also used for capture groups, so you can use that instead of list assignment if you like.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) # read every line
{
  my ($printer_code) = m/
    \(              # Match literal opening parenthesis
      ([^\)]*)      # Capture group (printer_code): Match characters which aren't right parenthesis, zero or more times
    \)/x;           # Match literal closing parenthesis
    # The 'x' modifier allows you to add whitespace and comments to regex for clarity.
    # If you use it, make sure you use '\ ' (or '\s', etc.) for actual literal whitespace matching!
}

__DATA__
(05-NW)HPLaserjet
```